# High pitched whine coming from my monitor

Tags: display, lcd, noise

I have a cheap LCD monitor (I-Inc) which works fine except for the speakers.
There is an extremely annoying buzzing whining high-pitched hum coming from the speakers.

It stops when I unplug the audio jack from the monitor.
It also stops when some things happen on the computer, such as when I open a new tab, strangely.  After the tab-opening process (.5 sec) stops, the noise starts again.

Also, it does not stop if sound is muted.

My laptop also does not make this sound without the monitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See your fourth word. Cheap electronics often whine. If your ears are sensitive enough *all* electronics whine. I have a hard time around any dimmer switches, most PDAs, cell phones, smart phones, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The electronics inside your case is causing electrical interference in the analog circuitry of your sound card. Try frobbing the spectrum spread settings in your BIOS, or switching to an external sound card.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to change that setting in the BIOS.  I think I'll have to use some speakers then.